# How to convert PyObjects to C data types?

Tags: c++, python-c-api

I am working on a project where I have to convert a user input C++ string variable to python executable code, I'm using the Python C API, so I have to go through the intermediary of converting the C++ string to a C string (or character array). Once I get there, I can't get the value to print once the code has been run. I'm searching for what the proper function in the Python C API is. I've tried `PyString_AsString(),` `PyBytes_AsString(),` and `PyObject_AsUTF8String`so far. Each of these functions has caused a memory issue when I try and run it with the code below. I've had to hard reboot my system with these three.

```
    Py_Initialize();
//the expected output, the player's output, and the compare functions
//PyObject* expectAnswer; //the expected answer for the level
PyObject* main = PyImport_AddModule("_main_");
PyObject* globalDictionary = PyModule_GetDict(main);
PyObject* localDictionary = PyDict_New();
PyObject* result = PyRun_String(cPlayerString, Py_file_input, globalDictionary, localDictionary);



Py_Finalize();
```

I am wondering whether I'm just not using the right call. `const char* PyUnicode_AsData()` looks promising, but I still have no idea whether I'd need to convert what I have into Unicode first.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The Q is unclear. I do not understand where you have problems with strings in Python API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're missing all error checking. Pretty much every Python C API call has a return value that indicates if an error has occurred, usually a `NULL` pointer. You *must* check these and handle the error if it has happened. I'll charitably assume you omitting this for the sake of a concise question.
2. `__main__`; double underscore.
3. Probably your real issue: [read the documentation about the start tokens](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.Py_eval_input). `Py_file_input` evaluates the string as if it were a Python file (i.e. an arbitrarily long collection of statements). A Python file doesn't "return" anything, and so `result` is probably a `None` object - you could always inspect it to confirm this. Your options are:

   - to use the token `Py_eval_input` which handles a single expression only and does return the result.
   - use the fact that a collection of statements (`Py_file_input`) will alter the local dictionary - any variables assigned to will be available in the dictionary afterwards and you can access those.
4. The object you eventually get is (probably) not going to be a string, so calling string functions on it may crash it  (`Py*_Check` functions are used to confirm the type and avoid this sort of crash). You probably want to use the [generic PyObject functions](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html) in the first instance. `PyObject_Print/Str/Repr` may be what you're after.

Comment: You are correct on all counts. I ended up reading the documentation, and you are correct, it worked how it should once I had the error handling and the double underscore for the main module!

Comment: Good :) I added a small edit that may help with strings (if you haven't already figured it out)

Comment: I did figure it out. I ended up using the PyObject_Str() myself, and then printed the resulting w_char!